# Why does Neural Network predict all input negative?

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, prediction, sentiment-analysis

I'm working on a sentiment analysis project in python with word2vec as an embedding method. (in my NON_ENGLISH corpus I considered every negative tweet with the 0 label, positive = 1 and neutral = 2)Since I'm really new in this field I don't have any idea as to why my model predicts everything negative. I surfed the net before and read something about the number of hidden layer and batches , etc. which related to this error but I'm not sure that I understood correctly.
here is my keras model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='elu', 
padding='same', input_shape= 
(max_tweet_length,vector_size)))
model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='elu', 
padding='same'))
model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='elu', 
padding='same'))
model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='elu', 
padding='same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=2, activation='elu', 
padding='same'))
model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=2, activation='elu', 
padding='same'))
model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=2, activation='elu', 
padding='same'))
model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=2, activation='elu', 
padding='same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))
```

thanks a lot!

Comment: How do you feed your data (outputs) and what is your logic behind your ouputs layers ? There are 2 outputs, how do you get output 0, 1 and 2?

Comment: Your code seems okay. Probably your data is unbalanced e.g: number of negative tweets is much more than positive/neutral.

Comment: @AmirHadifar my code is completely balanced the number of positive and negative tweets are the same and equal

Comment: replace your sigmoid activation function with softmax. As you mentioned in your question, you have 3 classes (positive/negative/neutral) so you should have 3 neuron for last dense layer.

Comment: @JérémyBlain Sorry is it possibe for you to explain about you're questions? I can't get the meaning

Comment: @ZahraBokaee what I meant is what Amir Hadifar suggest : you have 2 outputs in your last layer, but 3 classes. Is it a mistake ?

Comment: @AmirHadifar I have done what you said and nothing had changed

Comment: you have to change to 3 outputs neuron with softmax in last layer, then retrain your network ! (maybe freeze firsts layer to train faster)

Comment: @JérémyBlain I got it, but when I consider only 2 classes(positive and negative) for my code I faced with the same error!

Comment: @ZahraBokaee put all part of your code please.

Comment: @JérémyBlain I mean even I consider only 2 classes for my neural network the error still occure

Comment: @ZahraBokaee what was your architecture with only 2 classes ? Because it becomes binary classification, and you need only one neuron with sigmoid function in the last layer. Then you look at your output and depending on your threshold, your output become 0 or 1

Comment: @AmirHadifar I've done

Comment: @JérémyBlain So do you hacve any suggestion for solving this issue?

Comment: @ZahraBokaee Your training set is still with 2 outputs isn't it ? It should be, as your last layer, 3 outputs.

Comment: @JérémyBlain I gonna do what you mentioned. But I can't realize why do I face this error with only 2 classes too...

Comment: @ZahraBokaee with only 2 classes, what was you architecture ? As I mentionned in my previous comment

Comment: @JérémyBlain with only 2 classes I didn't change anything in my code above-If you take a look you see I added more details to my code.

Comment: @AmirHadifar Can you take a look in my code? Do you have any suggestion? – Zahra Bokaee 7 mins ago

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178945/discussion-between-zahra-bokaee-and-jeremy-blain).

Comment: @modesitt Could you please help me?